# How to detect url change by comparing first page url to second page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a privacy warning dialog that users can either click accept button, click decline button, click close button or click a link on the page to bypass - working with what Im give here. I need to fire a function if a user clicks a link on the page instead of clicking on any of the warning dialog's buttons.

The native unload handler gets blocked in some cases and also fires on page refresh. The hashchange event doesn't work as Im not using hashed urls. So I'm trying to capture the first page pathname, then on unload compare to the new page pathname and if they aren't equal run a function. Something isn't right here:

```
var origURL = window.location.pathname.slice(1);

$(window).unload(function(){
    var newURL = window.location.pathname.slice(1);
    if($(origURL) != (newURL)){
        //run function if page changes
    } else {
        //page hasn't changed - do nothing
    } 
})
```

Is there a better way to detect page change? I can't attach to a click event, as some links are done w/JS and not on an anchor.

Comment: Why not overlay the body to prevent click?

Comment: Just working with what Im given here - not my design

Comment: How about binding to `click` with `useCapture` option? It should give you the ability to check what was clicked, and if the element clicked is not one you allow, prevent the click from being executed. (using stopImmediatePropagation)

Comment: Is it not possible to just store the pathname of the first page you visit and compare it to any pathname on that change?

Comment: It is, but you won't be able to do anything about it at that time, some browsers might forbid you from changing URL at that point, you definitely cannot prevent the navigation at that time.